# Background doesn't wrap on multi-line TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have the following `TextView` with `layout_width` set to `"wrap_content"`, like so

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/another_text_view"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/another_text_view"
        android:background="@drawable/nice_background"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
```

And this is what happens:

[image]

Comment: show us the code to your RelativeLayout, please.

Comment: I will post the full .xml file soon. Also, i should mention that the TextView should be dynamic - it may end up as a single lone if enough room permits.

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I abandoned the idea :(

Answer (score 2):

I think this is just how `TextView` works. Unless you specify a fixed `width` or `maxWidth`, the "wrapping" of the text assumes that the text will now fill the available horizontal space. Your only option is to write your own version of `TextView` (or override the `onMeasure` method)...but that could get messy and complicated.

Answer (score 1):

this is beacuse of `android:paddingRight="26dp"` , remove it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to remove that from the post - as the padding gets added to the TextView on top of the gap. Removing it still leaves the gap.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView
        ....

        android:maxWidth="your preffered width"//prefer size in dp
        android:maxLines="number of lines you want"
        ....
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line: `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Comment: Removing this still leaves the gap :(